# Getting Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string, for Surface in react native but my import is correct

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to get a very basic surface/react ART sample up and running. But every-time I try to use a `<Surface>` it gives me the Invariant Violation. I'm not using default exports anywhere. I've installed the art plugin and linked it via `react-native link` and restarted/rebuilt everything, but I'm still getting the same error. I also tried importing ART from react native and then getting the Surface from that, but that also failed. Right now I'm testing with the iOS simulator using `react-native run ios`

```
import {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {Group, Shape, Surface, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export class Chart extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <View>
            <Surface width={100} height={100}>
            </Surface>
        </View>;
    }
}
```

Here is my dependencies for npm

```
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.1",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.1",
    "art": "^0.10.3",
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "d3": "^5.9.1",
    "d3-shape": "^1.3.4",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.2.0",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "fetch-intercept": "^2.3.1",
    "https-browserify": "0.0.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.2",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-os": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-voice": "^0.2.6",
    "react-navigation": "^3.1.5",
    "readable-stream": "^1.1.14",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.4.2",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tty-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't linked the library properly.

To link it properly you need to first navigate to `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART/` and find the `ART.xcodeproj`

[image]

Make sure you open your project in Xcode and then drag the `ART.xcodeproj` into the `Libraries` list.

[image]

Then you need to drag `libArt.a` from the products folder in the `Art.xcodeproj` into the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**.

[image]

Then in your `App.js` we can do the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ART } from 'react-native';
// notice that we import ART and then we can full the values Group, Shape and Surface out of ART
const { Group, Shape, Surface } = ART;

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Surface width={200} height={200}>
        <Group x={0} y={0}>
          <Shape d={"M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"} stroke="#000" strokeWidth={1} />
        </Group>
      </Surface>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

This should give us the following output:

[image]

Comment: That was it, thanks, wish it gave a slightly better error